# Mitzvot shanah rishonah mechilah

Tags: marriage, women, mitzvah

Could a wife be mochel the chiyuv of the husband with regards to the mitzvah of shanah rishonah

Comment: Kesubos 62B surely sounds like it’s possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's a dispute amongst the reishonim. It's also questionable if the mitzva applies nowadays.
It's brought in this shiur.
https://alldaf.org/p/23731
The chinuch says that she's can't be mochel.

Comment: It's also questionable if the mitzva applies to anything besides public service.

Comment: The semak applies it to the mitzvah of an onah, which I believe a woman can be mocheles